# Control Engineering In R

Tags: r

I use R, but lately are trying to implement Model Predictive Control as applied in Control Engineering on my models, but it seems that this area in R is non-existent as compared to Matlab where it is quite easy to do System Identification and create transfer functions which can be deployed inside the Model Predictive Control module. Anybody knows where to look, or which packages to use for MPC and transfer functions in R to build MPC models?

Comment: This question is quite broad. SO is a forum for focused questions on programming problems. Please refine your question with examples of what you have tried, as well as sample data. Otherwise, this question will be closed as off topic.

Comment: Have a look at the [CRAN Task views](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) for packages related to specific fields.

Answer (score 1):

There are a growing number of Python packages for control engineering. One option is to use the [reticulate R package](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/03/26/reticulate-r-interface-to-python/) to interface to Python functions. Here are some Control Engineering packages in Python:

- [SciPy.signal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) for signal processing and system modeling
- [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html) for Laplace transforms and differential equation analytic solutions
- [Control Systems Library](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.2/)
- [Chemical Process Control](https://github.com/jckantor/CBE30338) from Jeff Kantor, Notre Dame
- [Process Dynamics and Control in Python](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/) at BYU (my course)
- [Advanced Control and Machine Learning in Python](https://apmonitor.com/do/) at BYU (also my course)

Here is an example of running MPC in Python on the [Temperature Control Lab](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/AdvancedTemperatureControl).

[image: Temperature Control Lab MPC]